# JavaScript scroll bar isn't looking the way it should

Tags: javascript, html, css

I had a perfectly working scroll to the top of page button working, with a script tag in my html file.

I have since changed the file name to Home.php and the tag still works the way it should, i.e. button to appear as soon as user scrolls down on the page, but it fills the whole bottom of the page now rather than just appear in the bottom right.

What it should look like inside of Home.html:

[image: Correctly Working]

However this is what it looks like now in Home.php:

[image: Filling the whole of the page]

The Scrollbar.js file

```
// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

and a snippet of the code inside of Home.php

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/ScrollBar.js"></script> <!-- This is linking to my external JavaScript code for the scroll to top of the page button -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="SlideShow.js"></script> <!-- Linking to my external Javascript code for the top middle image slideshow-->       

    <section id="content"> 
        <div class="container">
            <section id="grid" class="clearfix">    
                <div class="cf show-grid">


                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="grid-full"> 
                            <a href="Index.html"><img class="Logo" src="Images/TLogo.png" alt="Website Logo"></a> 
                        </div>
                    </div> 



            <button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>
```

CSS:

```
#myBtn {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Fixed/sticky position */
    bottom: 20px; /* Place the button at the bottom of the page */
    right: 30px; /* Place the button 30px from the right */
    z-index: 99; /* Make sure it does not overlap */
    border: none; /* Remove borders */
    outline: none; /* Remove outline */
    background-color: #eee; /* Set a background color */
    color: black; /* Text color */
    cursor: pointer; /* Add a mouse pointer on hover */
    padding: 15px; /* Some padding */
    border-radius: 10px; /* Rounded corners */
}

#myBtn:hover {
    background-color: #555; /* Add a dark-grey background on hover */
        color: white; /* Text color */
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what JS code you have since it's a style issue, you should provide your CSS code instead

Comment: ...and how is this question related to PHP?

Comment: Will paste the CSS in now. @MagnusEriksson in case it was something to do with jS running inside of the PHP page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing some CSS styles are over-riding the styles defined in `#myBtn`.

Try adding the following CSS to the button and check.

```
#myBtn {
    width: auto;
    left: auto;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. It's fixed, I wonder why it worked before without this added code? Either way Im one happy girly!

Comment: I think there might be some styles for `button` which are already declared in your stylesheet. You can find them out in the Developer Console. Anyhow glad it helped !

Comment: Hi @AllanJeberaj I definitely have other code for button but none are called myButton so I wonder why it’s trying to apply the other button styling which is just called button? Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

Put the script tag in php file at the bottom of the code inside body tag and it should definitely work...!

Comment: Hello, I tried to paste the script tag inside of the body tag within the footer.php file, however it still fills the whole bottom space of the page as appose to just the small square, this is a rather strange one.